# Why doesn't my bubble sort work for double data type?

Tags: c++, arrays, double, bubble-sort

I'm trying to write a function which sorts an array using bubble sort. The version i wrote for an integer array seems to work fine. But the version for a double array does nothing (It returns an array which is exactly like the input array). I'm relatively new to c++ and coding in general. 
This one works fine.

```
void swap(int *xp, double *yp)
{
    double temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}
void bubblesort(int arr[],int size)
{
    bool fin;
    while(fin)
    {
        fin=false;
        for (int i=0;i<size-1;i++)
        {
            if (arr[i]>arr[i+1])
            {
                swap(&arr[i],&arr[i+1]);
                fin=true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this function doesn't seem to work

```
void swap(double *xp, double *yp)
{
    double temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}
void bubblesort(double arr[],int size)
{
    bool fin;
    while(fin)
    {
        fin=false;
        for (int i=0;i<size-1;i++)
        {
            if (arr[i]>arr[i+1])
            {
                swap(&arr[i],&arr[i+1]);
                fin=true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `bool fin = true;` before entering into while loop ..

Comment: Youre relying on UB, `fin` is not initialized. Your compiler should have warned (if it didnt, crank up the warning level)

Comment: @Borgleader Thanks, that seemed to do the trick. but how come that didn't cause problems in the integer version. Also how do you crank up the warning level (I use Codeblocks with mingw)

Comment: @RaheebHassan *how come that didn't cause problems in the integer version* -- It will only cause trouble when it comes time to demo your program to your biggest potential customer, and your program crashes.  That is the nature of undefined behavior -- anything can happen at any time..

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. Sometimes it actually works, but you can't rely on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one of the comments specify, you have not initialized the **bool fin**, which would lead to [UB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

In simple terms, the variable **fin** is not initialized and reading an uninitialized variable leads to undefined behavior.

So don't do it. The moment you do, your program is no longer guaranteed to do anything you say, probably the reason why it's working in one case and not in the other.